# Jasmine Cannot Find Spec Files

Tags: jasmine

Hi I am having trouble running jasmine because it cannot find the spec files.

my jasmine.json which is in the root folder is this

```

```
{
  "spec_dir": "test",
  "spec_files": [
    "integration-testing/*.spec.js"
  ],
  "helpers": [
    "helpers/**/*.js"
  ],
  "stopSpecOnExpectationFailure": false,
  "random": false
}
```

```

and my folder structure is this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try doing `"**/*[sS]pec.js"` for spec files and use the capital or lowercase 's' depending on what the 's' is in your file.

Comment: hi henry, thanks for answering. I tried it but still can't find my spec files.

Comment: The spec path is relative to the location of your directory where you specify it in the '.json' file

Comment: So my jasmine.json is the base level of the project. my tests are inside the test folder. the test folder is in the base level of the project. from what i understood, ```spec_dir: "test"``` and ```spec_files: [ "integration-testing/*.spec.js" ] but it isn't working.